# How do I extract subdocument in laravel mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

Hello Good Developers,

I am using [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package to query my MongoDB from Laravel.

Here's Fiddle for my query: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qzbNN8Siy-3

I have following JSON

```
[{
    "id": "GLOBAL_EDUCATION",
    "general_name": "GLOBAL_EDUCATION",
    "display_name": "GLOBAL_EDUCATION",
    "profile_section_id": 0,
    "translated": [
      {
        "con_lang": "US-EN",
        "country_code": "US",
        "language_code": "EN",
        "text": "What is the highest level of education you have completed?",
        "hint": null
      },
      {
        "con_lang": "US-ES",
        "country_code": "US",
        "language_code": "ES",
        "text": "\u00bfCu\u00e1l es su nivel de educaci\u00f3n?",
        "hint": null
      }...
    {
     ....
    }
]
```

I am trying to run following command

```
db.collection.find({ 'id': "GLOBAL_EDUCATION" },{_id:0, id:1, general_name:1, translated:{ $elemMatch: {con_lang: "US-EN"} }})
```

Expecting result like this

```
[
  {
    "general_name": "GLOBAL_EDUCATION",
    "id": "GLOBAL_EDUCATION",
    "translated": [
      {
        "con_lang": "US-EN",
        "country_code": "US",
        "hint": null,
        "language_code": "EN",
        "text": "What is the highest level of education you have completed?"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Everything is fine while query directly in MoDB but issue arise when I am trying this in Laravel.
I've tried every possible known function from MongoDB package. but Not able to do this.
here's my Array

```
$findArray = [
        [
            'id' => "GLOBAL_EDUCATION",
        ],
        [
            '_id' => 0,
            'id' => 1,
            'general_name' => 1,
            'translated' => [
                '$elemMatch' => ['con_lang' => "US-EN"]
            ],
        ]
];

$model = GlobalQuestions::raw()->find($findArray) //OR
$data = GlobalQuestions::raw(function($collection) use ($findArray){
        return $collection->find($findArray);
});
```

What I am doing wrong here, is this kind of Find() not possible here and I've to do this by aggregation?

Comment: getting any errors/log entries? those would help

Comment: When I run the first find I am getting a Blank Cursor Object and when I am running the second kind of find, I am getting Blank Collection

Comment: I am able to get data using aggregation and Pipelines using following function
`GlobalQuestions::raw(function($collection) {
            return $collection->aggregate([])
});`

But I don't want to use aggregation over normal find query

Comment: try printing this: `print_r(iterator_to_array($data));` in the last line of your code in the question

Comment: It returns blank array, tried Iterating, Hydrating and Looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one answered this, I am posting the solution if someone is having the same issue.
Doing some more R&D on the same I was able to do this using [where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) and [Project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) as well by [Aggregation Pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

**----- Using Where() and Project() ------**

```
$projectArray = [
    '_id' => 0,
    'id' => 1,
    'general_name' => 1,
    'translated' => [
        '$elemMatch' => ['con_lang' => "FR-FR"]
    ],
];

$data = GlobalQuestions::where('id', '=', 'GLOBAL_EDUCATION')
    ->project($projectArray)
    ->get();
```

**--- Using Aggregation and $unwind ---**

```
$data = GlobalQuestions::raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$match' => [
                'id' => "GLOBAL_EDUCATION"
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$unwind' => '$translated',
        ],
        [
            '$match' => [
                'translated.con_lang' => "US-EN"
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$project' => [
                '_id'=> 0,
                'id'=> 1,
                'general_name' => 1,
                'translated' => 1,
            ]
        ]
    ]);
})->first();
```

Comment: whats that mean translated  =>1 ?

Comment: `translated` field is an array which contains two items in array i.e `con_lang ` and `text` using projection I am selecting only the fields that I require